# Style getting screwed up with hash in URL

Tags: css

I have some pages that are loaded with a hash/anchor in the url.  When we do this it screws up the padding/margin of the document.  Without it, it works fine.

What's even stranger is if I use the browser tools to get to the css and disable the margin and padding and then reenable it, it looks fine.  We are using a third party web site to serve our site which means we're kind of locked into a CMS type of service and our hands are tied to a certain extent as to how much we can customize our pages.  So, therefore, we have multiple css files referenced and so forth.

If you look at the two urls below you'll see the issue in the one with the #company_settings appended to the end of the url.  If you then use inspect element in chrome to look at the header and disable and reenable the custom.css:2 for margin and padding, you'll see it then fixes the problem.  Any idea why this is happening and if there's something I can do in css to fix this?  Thanks.

http://www.patriotsoftware.com/patriot-pay-help-center-payroll-settings

vs

http://www.patriotsoftware.com/patriot-pay-help-center-payroll-settings/#company_settings

Comment: 'Patriot Software'. Sounds a bit creepy! Seriously though, tell us which browser you're using and attach some screenshots.

Comment: Here it is normal - http://i41.tinypic.com/i5q9v8.png  and here it is screwed up. http://i39.tinypic.com/xms5xx.png  I've tested it in chrome, firefox and IE9.  All do the same thing.

Comment: Very interesting... the HTML appears identical. And it's not happening in JS. Good luck figuring it out, remember to post back if you do discover what it is.

Comment: it's worth noting this only seems to have when the anchor is `company_settings`: http://www.patriotsoftware.com/patriot-pay-help-center-payroll-settings/#company_settings2

Comment: Theres a lot of javascript files running for this file. Are you certain none of these are linking to `#company_settings` and bugging?

Comment: Fairly sure it's not JS, it happens when JS is disabled.

Comment: Actually looking at the content of this site it doesn't look serious. Is this a real company? If so, you would be well advised not to make that content public. There is such a thing as caching...

Comment: There's one bit of javascript that uses the hash to know what section of the box menu to expand.  As for the content, yes it's just placeholder stuff for now.  It's not being promoted live yet.

Comment: Whoa. I opened up the source and was immediately overwhelmed. Looks like lots of things could be causing this issue... I'd pay some TLC toward your layout, for instance you have parents with static widths that are smaller than the static widths of their children. Recipe for trouble!

Comment: Seems like it's about `<div class="ec_header" id=""></div>`, because when I put `#company_settings` or `#getting_Started` behind the URL, the header image will be cutoff, but when I use an anchor identifier which does not exist (like, for example, `#anotheranchor` or `#blahblahblah`), the header image is not been cut off.

Comment: @geoffswartz This question was asked 4 years ago. Have you since figured out the problem and a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Using a hash in the URL signals the browser to scroll to a specific location of the document.

And the browser is exactly doing so.

If you can edit skin.css (which sounds so by it's name), go into line 6:

```
#foxboro_header {width:100%;overflow:hidden;}
```

Change it, remove the overflow rule:

```
#foxboro_header {width:100%;}
```

This should make it work.

BTW if it's a block element, the width is automatically set to `100%`. Setting it would be redundant then.

Next to that the code of the page is full of validation errors, deal with them otherwise you might run into more and more problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue using hash.

There is/was a some bug with `display: table` and hash url. I changed it to `display: block` and it was working correctly afterwards.

Hope it helps someone.